# Python checking file content with string

Tags: python

Hello! I have the following script:

```
import os
import stat

curDir = os.getcwd()

autorun_signature = [ "[Autorun]",
                      "Open=regsvr.exe",
                      "Shellexecute=regsvr.exe",
                      "Shell\Open\command=regsvr.exe",
                      "Shell=Open" ]

content = []

def read_signature(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path) as data:
            for i in range(0,5):
                content.append(data.readline())
    except IOError as err:
        print("File Error: "+   str(err))

read_signature(os.getcwd()+'/'+'autorun.inf')

if(content==autorun_signature):
    print("Equal content")
else:
    print("Not equal")
```

It prints not equal, then I tried this method:

```
import os
import stat

curDir = os.getcwd()

autorun_signature =  "[Autorun]\nOpen=regsvr.exe\nShellexecute=regsvr.exe\nShell\Open\command=regsvr.exe\nShell=Open"

content = ""

def read_signature(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path) as data:
            content = data.read()
    except IOError as err:
        print("File Error: "+   str(err))

read_signature(os.getcwd()+'/'+'autorun.inf')

if(content==autorun_signature):
    print("Equal content")
else:
    print("Not equal")
```

It also print not equal!
I want to store the content of autorun.inf file in script and every time i find such file I want to check its content if it is or not, I could not do, can anyone help me?
the content of autorun.inf:

```
[Autorun]
Open=regsvr.exe
Shellexecute=regsvr.exe
Shell\Open\command=regsvr.exe
Shell=Open
```

Comment: If you print `content` after reading it, what does it display?

Comment: You should parse your text into dictionaries and then compare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linebreaks under Windows `\r\n` are different from Linux's `\n`.

So try replacing `\n` with `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to the fact that Windows new lines are `\r\n` instead of `\n`.
Also, you should escape the `"\"`, so instead use`"\\"`.